# Phpmyadmin, can't load template, error opening

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, errortemplate

Established lampp (Apache 2, PHP, MySql)
When prompted `localhost` and `localhost/info.php` everything works fine.

```
   PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13

System  Linux laptop-Lenovo-G580 3.16.0-38-generic #52~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 09:43:57 UTC 2015 x86_64
Build Date  Sep 29 2015 15:24:22
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php5/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
PHP API     20121113
PHP Extension   20121212
Zend Extension  220121212
Zend Extension Build    API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build     API20121212,NTS
Debug Build     no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Signal Handling    disabled
Zend Memory Manager     enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support    enabled
DTrace Support  enabled
Registered PHP Streams  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk
```

But it is necessary to request `localhost/phpmyadmin` pops code.

```
addJSON( 'options', PMA_RecentTable::getInstance()->getHtmlSelectOption() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
'; } // Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script $GLOBALS['db'] = ''; $GLOBALS['table'] = ''; $show_query = '1'; // Any message to display? if (! empty($message)) { echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message); unset($message); } $common_url_query = PMA_generate_common_url('', ''); // when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display // all MySQL-related information if ($server > 0) { include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php'; include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php'; // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname // if a value is set $server_info = ''; if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']); if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ' ('; } } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= PMA_DBI_get_host_info(); } if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ')'; } $mysql_cur_user_and_host = PMA_DBI_fetch_value('SELECT USER();'); // should we add the port info here? $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']) ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'] : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']); } echo '
' . "\n"; echo '
'; if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 ) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('General Settings') . '
'; echo '

    '; /** * Displays the MySQL servers choice form */ if ($cfg['ServerDefault'] == 0 || (! $cfg['NavigationDisplayServers'] && (count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 || ($server == 0 && count($cfg['Servers']) == 1) ) ) ) { echo '
    '; include_once 'libraries/select_server.lib.php'; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_host.png') . " " . PMA_selectServer(true, true); echo '
    '; } /** * Displays the mysql server related links */ if ($server > 0 && ! PMA_DRIZZLE) { include_once 'libraries/check_user_privileges.lib.php'; // Logout for advanced authentication if ($cfg['Server']['auth_type'] != 'config') { if ($cfg['ShowChgPassword']) { $conditional_class = 'ajax'; PMA_printListItem( PMA_Util::getImage('s_passwd.png') . " " . __('Change password'), 'li_change_password', 'user_password.php?' . $common_url_query, null, null, 'change_password_anchor', "no_bullets", $conditional_class ); } } // end if echo '
    '; echo '
    ' . "\n" . PMA_generate_common_hidden_inputs(null, null, 4, 'collation_connection') . ' ' . "\n" . ' '. PMA_Util::getImage('s_asci.png') . " " . __('Server connection collation') . "\n" // put the doc link in the form so that it appears on the same line . PMA_Util::showMySQLDocu( 'MySQL_Database_Administration', 'Charset-connection' ) . ': ' . "\n" . ' ' . "\n" . PMA_generateCharsetDropdownBox( PMA_CSDROPDOWN_COLLATION, 'collation_connection', 'select_collation_connection', $collation_connection, true, 4, true ) . '
    ' . "\n" . '
    ' . "\n"; } // end of if ($server > 0 && !PMA_DRIZZLE) echo '

'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Appearance Settings') . '
'; echo '

    '; // Displays language selection combo if (empty($cfg['Lang']) && count($GLOBALS['available_languages']) > 1) { echo '
    '; include_once 'libraries/display_select_lang.lib.php'; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_lang.png') . " " . PMA_getLanguageSelectorHtml(); echo '
    '; } // ThemeManager if available if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ThemeManager']) { echo '
    '; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_theme.png') . " " . $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']->getHtmlSelectBox(); echo '
    '; } echo '
    '; echo PMA_Config::getFontsizeForm(); echo '
    '; echo '

'; // User preferences if ($server > 0) { echo '

    '; PMA_printListItem( PMA_Util::getImage('b_tblops.png')." " .__('More settings'), 'li_user_preferences', 'prefs_manage.php?' . $common_url_query, null, null, null, "no_bullets" ); echo '

'; } echo '
'; echo '
'; echo '
'; if ($server > 0 && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Database server') . '
'; echo '

    ' . "\n"; PMA_printListItem( __('Server') . ': ' . $server_info, 'li_server_info' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Server type') . ': ' . PMA_Util::getServerType(), 'li_server_type' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Server version') . ': ' . PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . ' - ' . PMA_MYSQL_VERSION_COMMENT, 'li_server_version' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Protocol version') . ': ' . PMA_DBI_get_proto_info(), 'li_mysql_proto' ); PMA_printListItem( __('User') . ': ' . htmlspecialchars($mysql_cur_user_and_host), 'li_user_info' ); echo '
    '; echo ' ' . __('Server charset') . ': ' . ' '; if (! PMA_DRIZZLE) { echo ' ' . $mysql_charsets_descriptions[$mysql_charset_map['utf-8']] . "\n"; } echo ' (' . $mysql_charset_map['utf-8'] . ')' . "\n" . ' ' . "\n" . '
    ' . "\n"; echo ' 

'; echo '
'; } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Web server') . '
'; echo '

    '; if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { PMA_printListItem($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'li_web_server_software'); if ($server > 0) { $client_version_str = PMA_DBI_get_client_info(); if (preg_match('#\d+\.\d+\.\d+#', $client_version_str) && in_array($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['extension'], array('mysql', 'mysqli')) ) { $client_version_str = 'libmysql - ' . $client_version_str; } PMA_printListItem( __('Database client version') . ': ' . $client_version_str, 'li_mysql_client_version' ); $php_ext_string = __('PHP extension') . ': ' . $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['extension'] . ' ' . PMA_Util::showPHPDocu( 'book.' . $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['extension'] . '.php' ); PMA_printListItem( $php_ext_string, 'li_used_php_extension' ); } } if ($cfg['ShowPhpInfo']) { PMA_printListItem( __('Show PHP information'), 'li_phpinfo', 'phpinfo.php?' . $common_url_query, null, '_blank' ); } echo ' 

'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
phpMyAdmin
'; echo '

    '; $class = null; // We rely on CSP to allow access to http://www.phpmyadmin.net, but IE lacks // support here and does not allow request to http once using https. if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['VersionCheck'] && (! $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('is_https') || PMA_USR_BROWSER_AGENT != 'IE') ) { $class = 'jsversioncheck'; } PMA_printListItem( __('Version information') . ': ' . PMA_VERSION, 'li_pma_version', null, null, null, null, $class ); PMA_printListItem( __('Documentation'), 'li_pma_docs', PMA_Util::getDocuLink('index'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Wiki'), 'li_pma_wiki', PMA_linkURL('http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/'), null, '_blank' ); // does not work if no target specified, don't know why PMA_printListItem( __('Official Homepage'), 'li_pma_homepage', PMA_linkURL('http://www.phpMyAdmin.net/'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Contribute'), 'li_pma_contribute', PMA_linkURL('http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/improve.php'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Get support'), 'li_pma_support', PMA_linkURL('http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/support.php'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('List of changes'), 'li_pma_changes', PMA_linkURL('changelog.php'), null, '_blank' ); ?> 

1) { trigger_error( __('You have enabled mbstring.func_overload in your PHP configuration. This option is incompatible with phpMyAdmin and might cause some data to be corrupted!'), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Nijel: mbstring is used for handling multibyte inside parser, so it is good * to tell user something might be broken without it, see bug #1063149. */ if (! @extension_loaded('mbstring')) { trigger_error( __('The mbstring PHP extension was not found and you seem to be using a multibyte charset. Without the mbstring extension phpMyAdmin is unable to split strings correctly and it may result in unexpected results.'), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check whether session.gc_maxlifetime limits session validity. */ $gc_time = (int)@ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'); if ($gc_time < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity'] ) { trigger_error( __('Your PHP parameter [a@http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime@_blank]session.gc_maxlifetime[/a] is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.'), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check whether LoginCookieValidity is limited by LoginCookieStore. */ if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] != 0 && $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity'] ) { trigger_error( __('Login cookie store is lower than cookie validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin.'), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check if user does not have defined blowfish secret and it is being used. */ if (! empty($_SESSION['auto_blowfish_secret']) && empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['blowfish_secret']) ) { trigger_error( __('The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).'), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check for existence of config directory which should not exist in * production environment. */ if (file_exists('config')) { trigger_error( __('Directory [code]config[/code], which is used by the setup script, still exists in your phpMyAdmin directory. You should remove it once phpMyAdmin has been configured.'), E_USER_WARNING ); } if ($server > 0) { $cfgRelation = PMA_getRelationsParam(); if (! $cfgRelation['allworks'] && $cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] == false ) { $msg = PMA_Message::notice(__('The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click %shere%s.')); $msg->addParam( '', false ); $msg->addParam('', false); /* Show error if user has configured something, notice elsewhere */ if (!empty($cfg['Servers'][$server]['pmadb'])) { $msg->isError(true); } $msg->display(); } // end if } /** * Warning about different MySQL library and server version * (a difference on the third digit does not count). * If someday there is a constant that we can check about mysqlnd, * we can use it instead of strpos(). * If no default server is set, PMA_DBI_get_client_info() is not defined yet. * Drizzle can speak MySQL protocol, so don't warn about version mismatch for * Drizzle servers. */ if (function_exists('PMA_DBI_get_client_info') && !PMA_DRIZZLE && $cfg['ServerLibraryDifference_DisableWarning'] == false ) { $_client_info = PMA_DBI_get_client_info(); if ($server > 0 && strpos($_client_info, 'mysqlnd') === false && substr(PMA_MYSQL_CLIENT_API, 0, 3) != substr(PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION, 0, 3) ) { trigger_error( PMA_sanitize( sprintf( __('Your PHP MySQL library version %s differs from your MySQL server version %s. This may cause unpredictable behavior.'), $_client_info, substr( PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION, 0, strpos(PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . '-', '-') ) ) ), E_USER_NOTICE ); } unset($_client_info); } /** * Warning about Suhosin */ if ($cfg['SuhosinDisableWarning'] == false && @ini_get('suhosin.request.max_value_length') // warn about Suhosin only if its simulation mode is not enabled && @ini_get('suhosin.simulation') == '0' ) { trigger_error( sprintf( __('Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to %sdocumentation%s for possible issues.'), '[doc@faq1-38]', '[/doc]' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Warning about mcrypt. */ if (! function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt') && ! $GLOBALS['cfg']['McryptDisableWarning'] ) { PMA_warnMissingExtension('mcrypt'); } /** * Warning about incomplete translations. * * The data file is created while creating release by ./scripts/remove-incomplete-mo */ if (file_exists('libraries/language_stats.inc.php')) { include 'libraries/language_stats.inc.php'; /* * This message is intentionally not translated, because we're * handling incomplete translations here and focus on english * speaking users. */ if (isset($GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang]) && $GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang] < $cfg['TranslationWarningThreshold'] ) { trigger_error( 'You are using an incomplete translation, please help to make it better by [a@http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/improve.php#translate@_blank]contributing[/a].', E_USER_NOTICE ); } } /** * prints list item for main page * * @param string $name displayed text * @param string $id id, used for css styles * @param string $url make item as link with $url as target * @param string $mysql_help_page display a link to MySQL's manual * @param string $target special target for $url * @param string $a_id id for the anchor, * used for jQuery to hook in functions * @param string $class class for the li element * @param string $a_class class for the anchor element * * @return void */ function PMA_printListItem($name, $id = null, $url = null, $mysql_help_page = null, $target = null, $a_id = null, $class = null, $a_class = null ) { echo '
'; if (null !== $url) { echo ''; } echo $name; if (null !== $url) { echo '' . "\n"; } if (null !== $mysql_help_page) { echo PMA_Util::showMySQLDocu('', $mysql_help_page); } echo '
'; } ?>
```

Tell me how to fix it?

```
Linux Mint
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.13
Apache2 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.6
Mysql 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```

Thank you

Comment: Please explain what you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Back up your databases and reinstall PHPmyAdmin. If the issue occurs try downloading a different version of PHPmyAdmin, also ensure that both your HTTPD and MYSQLD processes are running. But as for the specific error, if you explain what you've tried, we can better help to give you a relevant answer to your issue.